# How hibernate search(Lucene + hibernate core) works?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate search(built on top of Lucene). i have indexes created. now if i make a search, does it gets results only from the indexes created? i mean does it also queries the data from database table?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you came across this article from Javaworld discusses hibernate search using Lucene elaboratively: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2008/jw-07-hibernate-search.html

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to create a Lucene Query to run against Hibernates' `Search` class like this:

```
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, searchFields, new KeywordAnalyzer());
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = parser.parse("Text from entity to search for"); // Or any other valid query
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(hibernateSession);
org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, YOUR_TARGET_ENTITY_HERE.class);
List result = hibernateQuery.list();
```

I have no idea why they named the Hibernate result class `Query` too..

`searchFields` is a `String[]` containing the list of fields to search.

EDIT: More explanations.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply. you mean to say that indexes itself has data? what i understood was, lucene creates only indexes and if any search is made based on the indexes results are retrieved from database? Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: That depends on your setup, you can include/exclude entities and fields from the search index via the `@Indexed` and `@Field` annotations from Hibernate search. Fields included will be present in the search index. (Depending on the `store` attribute of the `@Field` annotation with or without the full data.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. i have a field annotated as : @Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED,store=Store.NO,name="someName"). i have indexed only one field. now if  i make a search, does results are retrieved from database based on the created indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Search is like a powerful helper for projects using Hibernate that needs full-text search capabilities. As such, "Hibernate Search" itself won't do searches in the database. It will search only in the indexes. That's the Lucene integration part. The Hibernate integration part is mostly around listeners, that would index the entities as documents every time you do some operation with the entity (saving, updating, removing, ...).